# what is the format specifier for string

Tags: swift, string

I use the following code

```
myFunc(code:String) {        
  let t1f = NSLocalizedString("uiDlg Title code %s", comment: "uiDlg Title");        
  let t1 = String.localizedStringWithFormat(t1f, code);
```

The string is declared in `Localizable.strings` file as

```
"uiDlg Title code %s" = "code [%s]";
```

if I call `myFunc("112233")` the result string on the screen contains strange characters as

```
code [Ä&:#]
```

if I use

```
let t1 = String.localizedStringWithFormat(t1f, code) + code;
```

The second code is displayed properly as

```
code [Ä&:#] 112233
```

Do I need to use %s as the format specifier for string? I could not find such sample code, all samples contains %d or %f for number formatting...

Comment: as a programmer new to swift, with C habbits, %s seems good enoth for my purpose. I did not know there is a difference between 'null terminated C string' and 'Swift string'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%s` is for a null terminated C string, the specifier for a standard Swift string is `%@`.

You can find the list of format specifiers in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)